# Write to zip - inside Azure Function

Tags: azure, function, zip, azure-functions, blob

I am using Azure function and in my function I want to create a zip file and then upload the zip to blob.

I am using this code in order to open a zip

```
  using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream($"{context.FunctionAppDirectory}\\Test.zip", FileMode.Create))
```

but I have this error : "Could not find file {context.FunctionAppDirectory}\Test.zip )"  after I deploy the function to azure and run it.

How can I open a zip and write files into this zip inside my azure function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` instead.

So like

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Test.zip"), FileMode.Create))
```